# Do I need to standardize or normalize my data?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normalization, standardization

I have the results of EPL season football stats with around 300 matches played.
Some data is the averaged results of past matches and some are different types of data such as odds.

It looks something like this (there are a lot more columns but this gives the idea):

| Team | Odds | Win % | Goal Avg | Concede Avg | Last 6 Goal Av | Last 3 Goal Av | Strength |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arsenal | 1.20 | 78 | 2.5 | 0.5 | 2.1 | 1.9 | ?? |
| Liverpool | 7.50 | 23 | 0.9 | 1.8 | 1.7 | 1.9 | ?? |
| Man. City | 4.10 | 60 | 1.1 | 1.2 | 1.5 | 1.6 | ?? |

The Strength column in each row will simply add the rows results together and divide by the total number of columns. (I plan on simply making the odds a negative number). The Strength basically just needs to be the sum of numbers in that particular row, divided by the amount of numbers. So basically 1.2 + 2.5 + 1.1 / 3 (as an example).

The question though is regarding how I normalise the data 'types', specifically the averages.
When normalizing averages, do I use the min/max of the *averaged* data or do I use the actual min/max values.

I've done some reading but it is going well over my head - I'm a web developer not a mathematician :)
And any type of pseudo code would be extremely helpful.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is that different methods achieve different things, and it isn't really clear what you want to achieve. "Prediction" seems to be meant to predict something but what? If you just compute it as you wrote you do, I'm not sure what this can predict with any reliability, and of course if you don't want your predictions to be good in any well defined sense, you can basically do whatever you want. (And if you want them to be good, you should probably choose a different prediction approach in the first place.)

Comment: @Lewian perhaps 'Prediction' should read 'Result'. It is meant as a bit of a game/fun and not a requirement to be entirely accurate or reliable. I do want the data to be reasonably good, but as far as reliability in it's predictions, I don't expect that.

Comment: What "result" exactly? Obviously if you just do it for fun, you can do what you want. A standard statistical approach would be to compare different methods by leaving out some data, trying to predict them, and then choose the method that works best ("cross-validation"). But for this there still needs to be a well defined prediction problem with the possibility to predict some of the results that you already know, for checking.

Comment: Apologies, I am not explaining myself very well. I am going to edit the question so hopefully I am clearer in what I want to achieve